# Return immediately and not execute chained mouseout event if mousedown was triggered inside mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, jquery-events, mousedown

Not sure how to go about this, but basically I wrote a tooltip plugin which removes the tooltips on either `mouseout` or `mousedown`.

If a `mousedown` event is triggered, it'll remove `$that.parent()` which is fine, and this removes the tooltip, but then if the user also triggers the mouseout event (which they will because the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are currently chained), it will then delete another DOM element which I don't want. So essentially I'm wondering if this is possible:

```
$that.on('mouseover', function() {

    // If this event is triggered within the mouseover event, don't run the chained mouseout event
    $that.on('mousedown', function() {
        $that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();
        return false;
    });
}).mouseout(function() {
  // If they clicked above, don't run this
    $that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();
});​
```

As far as I know, without using a global variable it's hard to access a `clicked` boolean set inside of that `mousedown` event e.g:

```
$that.on('mouseover', function() {
    clicked = false;
    // If this event is triggered within the mouseover event, don't run the chained mouseout event
    $that.on('mousedown', function() {
        clicked = true;
        $that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();
        return false;
    });
}).mouseout(function() {
    // If they clicked above, don't run this
    if (clicked) {
        $that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();
    }
});​
```

Any thoughts on how to construct this elegantly?

EDIT: The elements in `$that.parent().next()` are just a `<div class="js-tooltip"><span>Tooltip text</span></div>`

But this should be irrelevant as I'd like to just know if it's possible to return from that `mouseover` function if the `mousedown` was triggered without using a global variable.

Comment: You should explain a bit better what elements are exactly pointed in: `$that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();` I mean: what is `$that`, what element is: `parent` and who is: `.next()` ? You said that $that.parent() removes the Tooltip, but at what aims the `.next()` ???

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `$that.parent().next()` is the tooltip that gets cloned and inserted into the DOM after the current element that is being clicked on. `$that` in this case is referring to an input button called Cancel which adds the tooltip with some text that says: "Discard Changes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simply using the class filter like this?

```
$that.parent().next('.js-tooltip').fadeOut(100).remove();
```

This would simply not do anything if the next wasn't a tooltip, which should solve the problem as far as I understand.

Using your proposed method, it would be clearner to do `$that.clicked = false`.

Alternatively how about (if you want to keep the mouseover at all - this is just to demonstrate the principle; I'm not sure if it would work like this):

```
$that.on('mouseover', function() {

    // If this event is triggered within the mouseover event, don't run the chained mouseout event
    $that.on('mousedown mouseout', function() {
        $that.parent().next().fadeOut(100).remove();
        $that.off('mousedown mouseout'); //prevent that happening again
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Dude! I don't know why I wasn't targeting `.js-tooltip` before. That makes so much more sense and now my additional elements aren't getting deleted. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `mouseover`.

```
$that.on('mouseleave mouseup', function(e) {
     if( e.type === 'mouseleave'){
         // do the mouseleave stuff
     }else{
         // do the mouseup stuff
     }
});​
```

---

As you said, if the elements is dynamically created you should use:

`$(document).on('mouseleave mouseup', $that, function(e) {`

Comment: Although this didn't solve my issue, it introduced me to a new way of events by detecting through e.mouseleave which I never knew I could do before. Thanks so much!!!